# SQL grouping columns by comma when importing?

Tags: csv, mysql-workbench

I'm importing a csv into workbench with the table data import wizard.  SQL is grouping columns instead of reading them as distinct columns.  See photo:[image]

I'm just trying to get it to read the columns as distinct entities, instead of grouped.  thanks in advance.

Here's what the data looks like.

[image]

Comment: What does the first line look like? Is there any quote or special character after the first column? This might be hard for someone to answer without having actual data.

Comment: data above.  i also removed whitespace in column names, to no avail.

Comment: Use LOAD DATA INFILE instead of importer.

Comment: is that done with command line,  or within workbench? sorry for the ignorance here!

Comment: It is an sql command, you can run it from both clients.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the exported csv data is not formatted as the importer expects it by default. By clicking on the wrench button (beside the text "csv") you can show some options:

[image]

Change the field separator to comma. That is what your current separator is, it seems.